# Subsetting dataset when condition is true in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Using the code below, I could create my shiny app. When users select "yes" instead of "No", I would like the map to display only zip codes with at least 500 participants. As shown in the picture, "no" is selected by default.
I think I need some conditional statements to subset the data, but I dont know how to make this possible!

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(width=2,
                 radioButtons(
                   inputId = "ProjectID",
                   label = strong("Project ID"),
                   selected = "18",
                   choices = sort(unique(IDD_nhmap$ProjectID))
                 ),
                 
                 selectInput(
                   inputId = "Zip",
                   label = "Zip Codes With atleast 500 participants",
                   selected = "No",
                   selectize = TRUE,
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   choices = c("Yes", "No")),
                 
    ),
    ######################
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, shinyjs::useShinyjs(), leafletOutput("IDD_int_map1", height = "500px"))

    )
    
  ), # this closes mainPanel
   ), # this closes fluidRow
  br(),
  br()

) # this closes ui

####################################
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #ACS_Blacks
  IDD_mapdata_ <- reactive ({
    out_map <- IDD_nhmap %>%
      filter (ProjectID %in% input$ProjectID)
    return(out_map)
    list(Zip_Black)
  })
        IDD_mapdata_1 <- reactive ({
    out_map_1 <- lat_long %>%
      filter (ProjectID %in% input$ProjectID) 
    return(out_map_1)
    list(lat)
  })
        output$IDD_int_map1 <- renderLeaflet ({
    npal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "Greens",
                          domain = IDD_nhmap$Zip_Black)
    
    labels <- sprintf(
      "<strong>Zip Code=%s </strong> <br/> Count = %s <br/> Percentage = %s ",
      IDD_mapdata_()$Zip,
      IDD_mapdata_()$Zip_Black,
      IDD_mapdata_()$state_black
    ) %>%
      lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    leaflet (IDD_mapdata_(), options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25, zoomDelta =
                                                        0.25)) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron",
                       options = providerTileOptions(opacity = 2)) %>%  # you need this and ()to remove the backgroun (Mexico/Canda)
      clearControls() %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~npal2(Zip_Black),
        stroke = T,
        weight = 1,
        smoothFactor = 0.2,
        fillOpacity = 1,
        color = "black",
        label = labels,
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          interactive = TRUE,
          style = list(
            'direction' = 'auto',
            'color' =
              'black',
            'font-family' = 'sans-serif',
            # 'font-style'= 'italic',
            'box-shadow' = '3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)',
            'font-size' = '14px',
            'border-color' = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
          )
        ),
        
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
          weight = 2,
          bringToFront = T,
          # color = "#666",
          fillOpacity = 0.7
        )
      ) %>%
      
      setView(lng = IDD_mapdata_1()$long,
              lat = IDD_mapdata_1()$lat,
              zoom = 8) %>%
      
      addLegend(
        position = "topright",
        opacity = 1,
        values = IDD_nhmap$Zip_Black,
        #  colors= c("#FFFFE5", "#D9F0A3", "#78C679", "#006837"),
        pal = npal2,
        #title = (paste("%",input$ProjectID)) ,
        #title = (paste("%",input$ProjectID)) ,
        title = (paste("African American (ACS)")) ,
        labFormat = labelFormat()
      ) %>%
      addTiles(options = tileOptions(opacity = 2))  # you need this to remove the backgroun (Mexico/Canda) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Make this minimal and  reproducible. [MCVE] Getting a subset is a rather basic operation. If the many examples of getting subsets based on conditions in SO are not enough, then say which ones you tried and show the code. Then if still not having success it should suffice to request display of only 2 or 3 locations on a map that is available to anyone. (I cannot tell if that is part of your current code.) As **always** you should start by including `library` calls for any needed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Approach 1: checkbox input as filter/subset logic

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("fltr", "Filter mpg above 18", value = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    subset(mtcars, input$fltr | mpg <= 18) |>
      plot(mpg ~ disp, data = _)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Approach 2: reactive data

This approach might be preferred if multiple components (e.g., plots, tables) use the same optionally-filtered data.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydat <- reactive({
    dat <- mtcars
    if (isTRUE(input$fltr)) {
      dat <- subset(dat, mpg <= 18)
    }
    dat
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mpg ~ disp, data = req(mydat()))
  })
}
```